# Nested for loop not executing

Tags: c#, for-loop

Could anyone tell me why the nested for loop in the code below doesn't execute? I.e. The "Hello World" is not printed. The first loop is being executed.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {// Loop through array


            **for (int j = data.Length - 1; j < i; j--)**
            {
                // Loop backwards through array
                **Console.WriteLine("Hello World");**
                double subTotal = 0;   //Keeps track of current subsequence's value
                subTotal += data[j];
                if (bbestTotal < subTotal)
                {
                    bbestTotal = subTotal;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the value of data.Length?

Comment: try j > i as condition for 2nd loop

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: You want `for (int j = data.Length - 1; j > i; j--)` Currently, j will always be bigger than or equal to i, so the terminating condition will fail immediately.

Comment: Cheers guys brain was fried lol. Answer below solved it. Cheers.

Comment: @Fendorio then you might want to accept an answer :)

Comment: I can't yet, too soon since it was posted. I will accept when i can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is not executing because the loop condition

```
j < i
```

is `false` right at the beginning of the loop.

Since your loop advances `j` *down*, you should change the condition to

```
for (int j = data.Length - 1 ; j >= i ; j--)
```

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop variable `j` is initialized with top value and it is greater then `i` so use `j > i` instead of `j < i` in loop condition part.

Change

```
for (int j = data.Length - 1; j < i; j--)
```

to

```
for (int j = data.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that the condition `j < i` for the 2nd for loop is always false for all values of i. So it never goes inside the body of the 2nd for loop.
This should fix the problem:

```
for (int j = data.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
```